# will netflix work on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: netflix

I want to play my Netflix with my Ubuntu 12.04 but  before I download the player and screw something up I thought I would ask. I have not done anything yet.

Answer (score 1):

Netflix does not natively work on Linux; There is however an app which runs through Wine called Netflix Desktop
http://www.compholio.com/netflix-desktop/
Follow the instructions to download and install the program and watch movies/shows/etc.

Comment: I confirm it works, we use it at home without issues.

Answer (score 0):

Netflix, by default, will not work on Linux operating systems and it utilizes Silverlight technology which isn't available on Ubuntu. You can install Netflix Desktop through WINE or you can use virtual machines but the performance is not nearly as good as other machines.

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Here's the Netflix Desktop [link](http://www.compholio.com/netflix-desktop/)

---

or you can (possibly) use PlayOnLinux:

Using Squeeze repositary:

```
wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | apt-key add -
wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_squeeze.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```